# calling matlab function from Java

Tags: java, matlab, java-3d

Is it possible to call matlab function in java, if so, How can I use it.

For example there is a function in matlab called scatter3 and plotter3
How can I use them in Java.

Thank you

Comment: I found this project... see if this helps http://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/

Answer (score 0):

There are undocumented ways to call MATLAB from Java. You can learn a lot more about them from @YairAltman 's blog [Undocumented MATLAB](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/). Some of these methods are captured in the [matlabcontrol](https://code.google.com/p/matlabcontrol/) package.

Since the functionality is undocumented and subject to change (and since matlabcontrol is not updated frequently), you should not rely on this ability for anything critical.